# What are the Planck's "resonators" on his solution on the Black Body problem?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

On his paper "*On the Theory of the Energy Distribution Law of the Normal Spectrum*" from 1900, in wich M. Planck presents an overview on his prescription to obtain the expression for the eletromagnetic radiation spectral distribution of a black body. He introduce his methods in the following way:

> Let us consider a large number of monochromatically vibrating resonators - N of frequency ν, N' of frequency ν', N'' of frequency ν'',..., with all N large numbers - wich are at large distance apart and enclosed in a diathermic medium with light velocity c and bounded by reflecting walls.

My initial view was that those resonators were the atoms that compose the walls, radiating heat energy inside the cavity meanwhile being drived by the electromagnetic waves.

But this doesn't seem right by the Planck's words. I would like to known more specifically the nature of theses resonators.

Answer (score 0):

Without having read the paper myself, I expect that the resonators were intended to be abstract, not referring to a specific mechanism, especially since the structure of the atom was not known in 1900.  (Millikan's oil drop experiment was in 1909 and Rutherford's gold foil experiment was in 1911.)  It's not a crazy suggestion though.  A classical wave trapped in a box (e.g. light) will take on quantized energy levels, a mechanism which would have been known to Planck.

Comment: > *A classical wave trapped in a box (e.g. light) will take on quantized energy levels* How can classical wave "take quantized energy levels"? Are you refering to discrete set of resonant frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

By resonator he means a material body that interacts with EM radiation (hence, the resonator should have some electric charges in it, like an electric dipole with oscillating dipole moment), and can do so in a *resonant way*. This means such body oscillates with very small amplitude when acted upon by radiation of most frequencies, low and high(non-resonant forced oscillations), but for radiation of certain special range of frequencies $\nu,\nu+\Delta \nu$, it oscillates with high amplitude (resonant forced oscillations are happening), and thus also radiates a lot of its own EM radiation at this frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Given Planck's words

> ... monochromatically vibrating resonators ...
> which are at large distance apart and enclosed in a diathermic
> medium with light velocity c and bounded by reflecting walls.

I think these resonators are meant to be the electromagnetic
oscillation modes (i.e. standing EM waves) inside the cavity.

This would also be in line with his quantum postulate later on,
saying each of these oscillators can have only energy values
of $E=nh\nu$.